# Data from input not being accepted as arguments

Tags: python

When I enter data in to my function directly I get the right output but when I use input from the user to fill the list nothing happens. I don't get any errors or output what so ever.

The data from input should enter the list and the index from input should be deleted from the list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#class definitions
class record:

    def __init__(self,telephone,lastname,firstname):
        self.telephone = telephone
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Last name: {self.lastname}, First Name: {self.firstname}, Telephone: {self.telephone}"

class PhoneBook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.phonebook = []

    def addrecord(self, record):
        self.phonebook.append(record)
        return self.phonebook.index(record)

    def deleterecord(self, i):
        self.phonebook.pop(i-1)

    def printphonebook(self):
        x = 1
        for entry in self.phonebook:
            print(x,'. ',entry,sep='')
            x = x + 1

#Main
select = None
while select != 'exit':
    ph = PhoneBook()
    ph.addrecord(record(515,'fin','matt'))
    ph.addrecord(record(657,'fisher','bill'))
    select = input('Main Menu \n1. show phonebook \n2. add record \n3. remove record\nor "exit" to exit program\n')
    test = False
    while test == False:
        if select == '1':
            ph.printphonebook()
            test = True
        elif select == '2':
            x = int(input('Enter telephone number.\n'))
            y = str(input('Enter last name.\n'))
            z = str(input('Enter first name.\n'))
            ph.addrecord(record(x,y,z))
            test = True
        elif select == '3':
            i = int(input('Enter the record number youd like to delete.\n'))
            ph.deleterecord(i)
            test = True
        elif select == 'exit':
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid selection. Please try again.')
            test = True
```

The desired output would be getting the data to correctly enter and exit the list based on my x, y and z inputs and take out the specified index of the list based on the i input.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're expecting to happen and what's actually happening? You aren't printing anything anywhere expect for with `input`, so this won't display anything.

Comment: Can you print ph.phonebook at various points of code execution and check what is the output

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Yes when I print the list nothing new is added in beyond what i specified in the code comments is already working. Note that my functions are working; the input is the problem area.

Comment: @Carcigenicate per rules of stack overflow I didn't add any of that code in cause I felt it would detract from the question at hand. I specify in the explanation and code comments what portions are giving output and what sections are not.

Comment: @MatthewFinateri MCVEs are important, but they're only effective if they accurately represent your problem. If you're expecting printing, we'd need to see where you're expecting to see stuff printed from.

Comment: @Prune This is not the program. This is a snippit of code from it. I thought according to stack overflow rules I cant post the whole program because it is detracting from the question. If you want me too I can update the code to be the whole program so you can run through it and see the output but I have already explained the output in the question.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have updated the question to show the whole program. Try running it so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Two of us have referenced `MCVE`s; two have suggested basic debugging techniques.  I'll wait until you've had time to review and incorporate those into your question.  As the guidelines say, "Make it easy for others to help you."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clear and create a new Phonebook() object every time your first while loop runs.
I'm new and not skilled enough to fix every problem in a short amount of time.
You don't see your new entries, because they get wiped out every time.

Try using one while loop and a switch statement.

Comment: there is no switch statement in python :)